# Fetch returning undefined after parsing with json

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I am writing a JavaScipt application and am attempting to fetch data from a certain URL but am getting an undefined value. The expected value after fetching and converting it to json should result in an array. I am not sure why this is happening. I have put my code below:

```
  let promiseResponse = fetch("some-url");
  let response = await promiseResponse;
  // check if there was an error in fetching the data (no error detected)
  if(!response.ok) {
    alert("An error occured when attempting to fetch data.")
  }
  // a console.log statement here for the var 'response' results in "[object Promise]"

  let parsedPromiseResonse = response.json();
  let parsedResponse = await parsedPromiseResonse;
  // printing out the 'parsedResponse' var gives me [object Object]
  // printing out the 'parsedResponse[0]' var gives me undefined
```

EDIT: 
For more context, the data to be retrieved in the URL is formatted like this:

```
{"variants":["some-string","some-string"]}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like the object returned by the API doesn't have a `0` property

Comment: `parsedResponse` is an object, how are you "printing out" this variable? ... I'm also surprised that `response` is a Promise

Comment: your code is very clumsy though ... `let response = await fetch("some-url");` and `let parsedResponse = await response.json();` is how most people would write the above code - no need for so many intermediate variables that hold promises only to be awaited in the next line!

Comment: It should have a 0 property because it is an array (or at least it should be an array after being parsed).  I printed the object out through a 'console.log' statement

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry about the code quality! I am kind of new to using await/fetch and wanted to make the steps more explicit, just in case I was doing something wrong.

Comment: ah, no problem - can you show exactly the `console.log` statement ... you see, an object output in console.log usually outputs as an object unless you did it in a way that the object is being coerced to a string type

Comment: I printed it like this: 
`console.log(response)`

Comment: So the parsed response isn't an array, it's an object with an array as the `variants` property value? It doesn't make any sense to access the root with a `0`, but `parsedResponse.variants[0]` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the varients array, then this is how you will get the array values.

`parsedResponse["varients"]`

For the first index

`parsedResponse["varients"][0]`

Answer (score 1):

To access the json to have to call the entity **variants** then access to the items, something like

```
alert(parsedResponse.variants[0])
```

And the result should be

```
some-string
```